# Problems running svn+ssh from Jenkins in OS X using ssh keys

Tags: macos, svn, ssh, jenkins

Trying to run a simple

```
 svn list svn+ssh://...
```

from within jenkins on os X, as an execute shell step. The job is not linked to a SVN repository - I am trying to do an svn list manually on the tags folder without having jenkins downloading a copy of each tag.
but other jobs are connected to svn and jenkins checks out code fine.

I have [downloaded jenkins from here](http://ingorichter.blogspot.com/2011/04/jenkins-osx-installer.html) which runs jenkins as a daemon

The problem is ssh keys. After a few iterations, here where I am at.

In /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist I have set JENKINS_HOME as /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home (that's where jenkins gets installed), and in there I have created ssh keys, without passphrase (for now)

The actual command I am running is

```
svn --config-dir=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/.subversion list svn+ssh://...
```

to get around jenkins running shell steps as root without actually having root permissions (not sure why - jenkins is launched by loading /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist) and causing a permission error when it tires to read /var/root/.servers

in --config-dir=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/.subversion/config I have added

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -v -i /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/.ssh/id_rsa
```

so ssh can connect to the server. The last missing step now is that the shell expects the passphrase and cannot get it from Keychain (obviously)

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
```

I thought leaving an empty passphrase would do the job, but it doesn't. Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there is a workaround to "read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured" - the command expects terminal input and can't get it, nor can it get Keychain to provide it. It's all tied in with running as a daemon.

In the end I downloaded [the latest version of the jenkins installer](http://ingorichter.blogspot.com/2011/08/notable-changes-in-jenkins-os-x.html) and re-installed to run manually and not as a daemon, so it runs as me instead of some weird flavour of root, and the problem disappeared.